# Django MPTT - how to query based on URL segments

Tags: django, django-mptt, mptt

I have:

```
Home
    Things with Fur
        Dog
        Horse
    Basket Ball Games
        Twenty One
        Horse
```

Assuming the `slug` for each is `title.lower().replace(' ', '-')`, my URLs would be:

```
/home/
    /home/things-with-fur/
        /home/things-with-fur/dog/
        /home/things-with-fur/horse/
    /home/basket-ball-games/
        /home/basket-ball-games/twenty-one/
        /home/basket-ball-games/horse/
```

The `slug` field is `unique_together` with the `parent`.

I need to, based on the URL segements, query for the correct category. I can't simply query for the basket ball game `horse` with `Category.objects.get(mptt_level=2, slug=u'horse')`, because there happens to be a category with the slug `horse` under a different category, but at the same level. So, how am I supposed to query for my `horse` category correctly without climbing up the chain and checking each level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the full path to each item in the database.

Comment: I was dreading that :( but I found that storing a simple sha1 of the full path makes it a bit cleaner / smaller DB index for larger sites. Thanks, Daniel.