# How to display tree structure with hyperlinks in django views

Tags: python, django, django-mptt, mptt

I have in my databases a table called `nodes`
and where i have parent child relationship and i am using

http://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/tutorial.html

for nodes

Now i can display all the nodes in the same  and that is no problem.

But what i want is that i have folder like structure that if someone clicks of `parent folder` then i go to next view which will have its children only

and url will become

`www.example.com/downloads/parentfolder`

Then if user click on child folder1 then it shows its further children and url becomes

`www.example.com/downloads/parentfolder/childfolder`

how can i do that sort of thing

I want to do something like this

[Django MPTT - how to query based on URL segments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455161/django-mptt-how-to-query-based-on-url-segments?rq=1)

But he didnt explain how he did it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with routing as you do in app which has normal django models from urls.py like this.

```
#urls.py

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^downloads/(?P<parent_id>\d+)/$', ParentView.as_view(), name='parents_list'),
    url(r'^downloads/(?P<parent_id>\d+)/(?P<child_id>\d+)/$', ChildView.as_view(),
                                    name='childs_list'),
)
```

Write corresponding views, and you should be fine. Please bear in mind, I have used Class Based Views in above url example. Just write whatever type of views you are familiar with.

The first view will show parent or parents list from given parent id in url. The second view will show child inside parent given parent and child ids.

### Edit

Looks like your requirement is a bit complex, I found better solution here [Django-MPTT full path to child pages how to make?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460691/django-mptt-full-path-to-child-pages-how-to-make)

I hope it will solve your problem :)

Comment: i dont want id in url , i want to have full text description in urls. also what about if i have `downloads/7/8/9/55`

Comment: You can use slugs in that case, see this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#slugfield.

Comment: Updated the answer with solution link. Hope it helps.